# Как передать переменную(параметр) из TVполя в статичный php файл?

Tags: modx

Есть TVполя выведенные в допполя админки, в которых заказчик может менять адрес своей эл.почты (как просто текст так и mailto:). Сама почта работает через PhpMailer. Т.е. идет перехват AJAXом данных с формы и отправка их в php-обработчик(ну что то типа mail.php), в которых стандартный код PhpMailer. Так вот вопрос: как мне в этом самом файле поменять `$mail->addAddress('mail@mail.ru', 'List');` mail@mail.ru на данные из TV-поля.

Сейчас я вывел пока обработчик статичным файлом в сниппеты(пусть будет сниппет test_mail). Если **ручками** менять в сниппете адрес, то все нормально, он сохраняется и в файле. А как передать туда что-то типа переменной(параметра), чтоб заказчик менял свой емейл в TVполе - он менялся не только визуально на странице, но и уходил в этот самый mail.php и менял там адрес?

Пробовал [[!test_mail &mail_param=`[[*pmail]]`]] где: 
test_mail - сниппет (со статичным файлом mail.php), 
pmail - TVполе, где меняется адрес эл.почты.
Но в таком случае у меня вызывается сам сниппет на этой странице, а надо передать туда переменную(параметр) TVполя, да еще и сохранить этот сниппет, чтоб файл mail.php перезаписался с нужными данными...

Comment: адрес для писем  всегда из одного и того же tv-параметра берется? Этот tv-параметр(ы) задан для какого-то предопределенного ресурса(id) или ресурсы могут быть разными?

Comment: Да, изменение адреса будет привязано к главной странице, следовательно данные будут браться из одного TVполя для определенного ресурса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно в скрипте(mail.php), который отрабатывает ajax-запрос, подключить движок modX. После этого можно получить значение tv-параметра у нужного ресурса:

```
<?php
define('MODX_API_MODE', true);
require_once "path/to/modx/index.php"; // path/to/modx - корневая папка modX
/*
$modx->getService('error', 'error.modError');
$modx->setLogLevel(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR);
$modx->setLogTarget('FILE');
*/
$doc = $modx->getObject('modResource', 1); // ID ресурса главной страницы 
$email = $doc->getTVValue('pmail'); // `pmail` - название tv-параметра
```